# Can not read property "Buffer" of "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, mongoose, buffer

I am building an app in which I am filling a form which also has files. I am getting files from "req.file" and other things from "req.body". the "file" is not "required". The user can attach or cannot attach. when the user attaches, all goes well but when a user does not attach the file I found this error. `can not read property "buffer" of undefined.`. I have set mongoose schema type of "image" is "Buffer". Here is my code when I get a file and other data from "req".

```
image: req.file.buffer,

geolocation: req.body.geolocation,

details: req.body.details,

location: req.body.location,

status: req.body.status,

spam: req.body.spam,
```

Comment: Check `req.file` before you assign `req.file.buffer` to image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating your object before adding it to db, you need to check first that `req.file` is empty or not.

```
{
 image: req.file.buffer ?  req.file.buffer :  null; 
 geolocation: req.body.geolocation,
 details: req.body.details,
 location: req.body.location,
 status: req.body.status,
 spam: req.body.spam
}
```

So in case, your form does not have `req.file.buffer` it won't throw an a error.

Comment: i managed to solve it.
it should be ' ' rather than null.
i tried with " ". Maybe your case 'null' works. but thanks alot. :)